# 9V DC offset voltage at phase out of inverter section

Tags: inverter

[image]

In this circuit, the gate driver is powered with a 12V supply and there is no PWM given at the HI and LI. In this idle condition, I measured 9VDC on the HS pin. Once PWM is given on the HI and LI pins, it becomes 0V and starts switching. My worry is about the 9V present at the HS pin in idle condition when PWM is OFF.

What is the reason behind this 9V at HS  Pin? Can Someone explain how 9V is generated at this point?

Is there any measure can be taken to make that potential 0V in idle condition?

Comment: Because the output capacitor is left charged to 9 volt from some previous test.

Comment: Sorry for misleading image. There is no Inductor and Capacitor connected at the HS pin

Comment: Have you tried putting a 100 kohm resistor across D and S of lower MOSFET. The voltage is probably due to leakage current through the upper driver.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason behind this 9V at HS Pin? Can Someone explain how 9V is generated at this point?

100V is loaded with two series-connected large resistors. These resistors are basically the off-state resistances of the MOSFETs *(neglecting the output capacitances)*.

When an NMOS is off (i.e. the gate-source voltage is below the threshold, generally zero) the resistance across drain and source won't be infinite if a drain-source voltage is present, so there's going to be leakage current *(This is also known as "zero-gate drain current" i.e. drain current when the gate-source voltage is zero)*. The value of this current depends on the MOSFET and external conditions, and is unpredictable – datasheets give "max" value for specific conditions, though.

So, this is where that 9V comes from. With different MOSFETs the voltage could be different.

> Is there any measure can be taken to make that potential 0V in idle condition?

At idle you can keep the low-side NMOS on and the high-side NMOS off, unless otherwise is required. This will make the bridge voltage zero and keep the bootstrap cap charged. So you can start switching by turning off the low-side and, after some dead time of course (I don't know if a dead-time is generated by the HIP2211 internally), turning on the high-side.